# No me hace el update SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero poner todos los datos de una tabla, su campo agregado, al valor 1 (ahora mismo tiene el valor 0). Pues bien, estoy ejecutando la siguiente sentencia SQL (estoy usando MySQL):

```
UPDATE pedidos_remoto SET agregado VALUE 1;
```

Me da error de sintaxis pero no veo el fallo. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: estás usando sqlite? postgresql? oracle? h2? db2? access?

Comment: SQL, estoy ejecutando la sentencia en MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hace tiempo que no toco temas de SQL, pero creo que la sintaxix del `UPDATE` era algo así:

```
UPDATE nombre_tabla
SET columna = valor
WHERE condición;
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: El tema que en mi caso no hay ninguna condición, porque quiero cambiarle el valor de ese campo a todos los registros de mi tabla. Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Prueba a usar lo siguiente: `UPDATE pedidos_remoto SET agregado = 1; `

Comment: Efectivamente, ya funciona. Muchas gracias :)